# Run npm script using dependencies from parent directory

Tags: npm

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
my-project/
|-- package.json
|-- file1.js
|-- sub_folder/
    |-- package.json
    |-- file1.js
```

All of the dependencies for the entire project are inside `my_project/package.json` so the developer only has to run `npm install` in one place. However, inside `my_project/sub_folder/package.json` I have some scripts (no dependencies) that I'd like to be able to run.

```
$ cd my_project/sub_folder
$ npm run sript1
```

where `script1` uses some of the libraries installed in `my_project/package.json`. I achieve that by having the script directly run the npm package a directory up like this:

```
$ cat my_project/sub_folder/package.json
{
    "name": "sub-folder",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "script1": "../node_modules/.bin/tsc -p"
    }
}
```

This works fine on mac and linux but gives an error on Windows:

> '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

It'll work if I change `script1` to be

```
"script1": "..\\node_modules\\.bin\\tsc -p"
```

but of course that breaks Mac and linux. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I could move all the scripts up into the parent `package.json` but there are a lot of them and I'd prefer to keep them in the sub folder.